# 404 not found error when routing with Laravel

Tags: mysql, angularjs, laravel, http-status-code-404, laravel-routing

I am trying to follow David Mosher's tutorial on going end-to-end with angular JS on youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqAyiqUs93c.

Everything was going fine until I attempted to route the /auth/login and auth/logout urls to the Authentication Service, as seen in the video at about 14:30. When I attempt to login, I receive a 404 Not Found Error. I have tried messing around with the route's URL, but to no avail. I am running locally on MAMP with MySQL and Laravel.

Here's my code for routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return View::make('index');
});

Route::post('/auth/login/', 'AuthController@login');
Route::get('/auth/logout/', 'AuthController@logout');
```

and my code for AuthController

```
<?php

class AuthController extends BaseController {
  public function login()
  {
    if(Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::json('email'), 'password' => Input::json('password'))))
    {
      return Response::json(Auth::user());
    } else {
      return Response::json(array('flash' => 'Invalid username or password'), 500);
    }
  }

  public function logout()
  {
    Auth::logout();
    return Response::json(array('flash' => 'Logged Out!'));
  }

}
```

lastly, code for authentication service

```
angular.module("epicApp")
    .factory('AuthenticationService', function($http, $location){
        return{
            login: function(credentials){
                return $http.post("/auth/login/", credentials);
            },
            logout: function(){
                return $http.get("/auth/logout/");
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Can you copy the error url from console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only one problem is you have to replace all `/auth/login/` to `auth/login` and `/auth/logout/` to `auth/logout` in your route and angular script.

So your route should be,

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return View::make('index');
});

Route::post('auth/login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'AuthController@logout');
```

And js,

```
angular.module("epicApp")
    .factory('AuthenticationService', function($http, $location){
        return{
            login: function(credentials){
                return $http.post("auth/login", credentials);
            },
            logout: function(){
                return $http.get("auth/logout");
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this question still relevant, but you will get a 404 with any HTTP URL if inside the public folder the index file is not a .php.
You could just rename the index.html of your angular app.